# What is the solution of this error "Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\calonMhs_controller::update()"?

Tags: laravel

i have class update in controller laravel but it doesn't work

here error message
Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\calonMhs_controller::update()

here my class update in controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // Get data from table
    DB::table('calonmhs')->where('id_calonMhs',$id)->update($request->all());
    DB::table('asalSekolah')->where('id_asalSekolah',$id)->update($request->all());      
    DB::table('registrasi')->where('id_registrasi',$id)->update($request());      
    DB::table('ayah_calonmhs')->where('id_ayah',$id)->update($request->all());
    DB::table('ibu_calonmhs')->where('id_ibu',$id)->update($request->all());
    DB::table('wali_calonmhs')->where('id_wali',$id)->update($request->all());

    return redirect('/admin');

}
```

i hope update data will work

Answer (score 0):

The `$id` that is coming into the method is for a *single* model.  The typical approach would be to update that model within the `update()` method something like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $myModel = MyModel::find($id);
    $myModel->update($request->all());
}
```

Looks like your error is coming from trying to update a lot of models based on an `$id` that is for only one of them - perhaps the `id` doesn't fit for the remaining models.

If you are trying to update other models based on a FK to the original, it is much easier to use the relationship on the original model:

```
$myModel->relation()->sync(//whatever);
```